# Possible security risks for the following form submission in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create the page for a livetime chat app using Django and some Ajax. I have always used django forms, since it is more secure and clean if you are not very familiar with javascript. The below html and views.py don't use django forms, but instead go with the traditional method of using javascript. However, I am concerned that there might be security leaks with this following form, which I copied from another website. I believe I added the csrf token correctly, but is there anything else I need to consider? Thank you, and please leave any comments.

And this is the views.py.

```
def view(request):
    message = request.POST['message']
    username = request.POST['username']
    room_id = request.POST['room_id']

    new_message = Message.objects.create(value=message, user=username, room=room_id)
    new_message.save()
    return HttpResponse('Message sent successfully')
```

If there is an issue, please write the fixed code along with it so I could refer to it.

Comment: Django form doesn't add security but makes it easy to generate form html and do validation. The CSRF security is provided by django middleware nothing to do with Django form. And you can still use Django form for validation on your backend even with Ajax request.

Comment: @Ahtisham So... is my code fine then? Do I need to add something to improve security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use Django form. In your case you won't be returning the Django Form for rendering but only for backend validation. For example [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from app_name.models import Message


class MessageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
```

**views.py**

```
from app_name.forms import MessageForm

def send(request):
    form = MessageForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()

    return HttpResponse('Message send successfully.')
```

You can also handle form errors using [errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) attribute of form.

For CSRF protection when using Ajax you can check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax)